# Why do people use some thing like char*&buf?

Tags: c++

I am reading a post on Stack Overflow and I saw this function:

```
    advance_buf( const char*& buf, const char* removed_chars, int size );
```

What does `char*& buf` mean here and why do people use it?

Comment: Note that this is specific to C++ and meaningless in C. You might want to change the tag.

Comment: Switched the tag to "c++", since C doesn't have references.

Comment: A [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will give you a much fuller set of information than picking up scraps on the internet will.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means `buf` is a reference to a pointer, so its value can be changed (as well as the value of the area it's pointing to).

I'm rather stale in C, but AFAIK there are no references in C and this code is C++ <sub>(note the question was originally tagged [c](/questions/tagged/c))</sub>.

For example:

```
void advance(char*& p, int i) 
{       
    p += i;  // change p
    *p = toupper(*p); // change *p
}

int main() {
    char arr[] = "hello world";
    char* p = arr; // p -> "hello world";
    advance(p, 6);
    // p is now "World"
}
```

---

**Edit:** In the comments @brett asked if you can assign `NULL` to `buff` and if so where is the advantage of using a reference over a pointer. I'm putting the answer here for better visibility

> You can assign `NULL` to `buff`. It isn't an error. What everyone is saying is that if you used `char **pBuff` then `pBuff` could be `NULL` (of type `char**`) or `*pBuff` could be `NULL` (of type `char*`). When using `char*& rBuff` then `rBuff` can still be `NULL` (of type `char*`), but there is no entity with type `char**` which can be `NULL`.

Comment: why do people use some thing like this ? Is there any advantage of using this ? I think using char** buf also works right ? to provide a clean interface ?

Comment: that, and pointers can point to garbage or to NULL, but references are always valid.

Comment: It is cleanest to code using references than pointers, but under the covers is basically the same char** than char*&.

Comment: @brett, `char**` would also work but it permits NULL while `char*&` does not. Also the syntax is more natural you don't have to add another level of `*`.

Comment: @Motti what is the disadvantage of allowing assigning to NULL ? Also if I assign buff=NULL is it a syntax error?

Comment: @Brett: you can apply the same argument to *any* reference, not only reference to a pointer ('why use T& when you could use T*?'). Personally I favor T*& (actually I favor to typedef a TPtr type and use TPtr&) because the T** is often used to signify `pointer to head of array of pointers`.

Comment: @brett you can assign `NULL` to `buff` it isn't an error, what everyone is saying is that if you used `char **pBuff` then `pBuff` could be `NULL` (of type `char**`) or `*pBuff` could be `NULL` (of type `char*`). When using `char*& rBuff` then `rBuff` can still be `NULL` (of type `char*`) but there is no entity with type `char**` which can be `NULL`. I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: of course, if you used char** const pBuf then you wouldn't be able to set pBuf to NULL either (but you could still set *pBuf to NULL) - so you'll get the same effect as the reference. You will have to dereference pBuf everywhere, though - so the the reference is definitely cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

`buf`'s a (C++) reference to a pointer. You could have a `const char *foo` in the function calling `advance_buf` and now `advance_buf` can change the `foo` pointer, changes which will also be seen in the calling function.